# Style the first letter of every word instead of only the first word?

Tags: html, css, cpu-word

To style the first letter I use :first-letter in a paragraph.

```
p:first-letter { 
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #8A2BE2;
}
```

But what if I want to style the the first letter of every word in the paragraph?

Comment: Maybe this will lead you in a good direction: http://community.sitepoint.com/t/css-target-the-first-letter-of-every-word/8108/2

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS way without adding extra elements to the markup (or to the DOM tree with JavaScript), because there is no CSS selector for the purpose.

If you add markup for each word, you can use `:first-letter` on them if you make them inline blocks (`:first-letter` cannot be used on inline elements, which is what `span` is by default):

```
<style>
.word {
  display: inline-block;
}
.word:first-letter {
  font-size: 200%;
  color: #8A2BE2;
}
</style>
<span class=word>Hello</span> <span class=word>world</span>
```

Alternatively, you can of course use markup for each initial letter, e.g. `<span class=word>H</span>ello <span class=word>w</span>orld`, and use a simple selector like `.word` to set the character formatting. Using “word markup” might, however, a) look better in HTML source, b) let you easily format the entire words, too, should that become desirable, and c) avoid potential risks caused by breaking a word with markup (very small risks probably, but people are sometimes worried about them).